# Why does this simple .html file with javascript not work?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

This code should work. Why doesn't it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<h1> The "^" operator in Javascript </h1>

<p id = "foo"></p>

<script>

function f(){
//vars
var a = 5;
var b = 13;
var c = a ^ b;
var binA = a.toString(2);
var binB = b.toString(2);
var binC = c.toString(2);
var strA = a.toString();
var strB = b.toString();
var strC = c.toString();

//make output string
var lineA = "a = " + strA + " = " binA + ", ";
var lineB = "b = " + strB + " = " binB + ", ";
var lineC = "c = " + strC + " = " binC + ", ";
var outputStr = lineA + lineB + lineC;

//output
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = outputStr;

}

f();

// For some reason this shows the contents of the header only

</script>
</body>
```

I did the toString() conversions on a, b and c because I can't understand why the output is failing to display in Google Chrome. I recognize they should not be necessary. But I wanted to make the code as kosher as possible. I have concatenated the string as substrings because in a previous iteration of this code, commenting out the 'C' section of the string concatenation allowed the 'A' and 'B' related sections of the output string to display. Plus it keeps the visual format regular which I am trying to use to error-check.

Comment: If only you would know how to use jsfiddle's **JS Hint** feature!!!! pity you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error, you missed '+' before the binA, binB and binC

```
var lineA = "a = " + strA + " = " + binA + ", ";
var lineB = "b = " + strB + " = " + binB + ", ";
var lineC = "c = " + strC + " = " + binC + ", ";
var outputStr = lineA + lineB + lineC;
```

output prints as below when I fixed that error in ff and chrome

```
a = 5 = 101, b = 13 = 1101, c = 8 = 1000,
```

Comment: How do I declare this question 'answered'?

Comment: @DanielWinterbottom : there is "check" mark on the left side of the question body! Click on that which will turn to green and then the answer will be mark as "accepted"

Answer (score 2):

Updated the code, you have missed out '+'

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ritesh14887/egor6j1o/)

```
var lineA = "a = " + strA + " = " + binA + ", ";
var lineB = "b = " + strB + " = " + binB + ", ";
var lineC = "c = " + strC + " = " + binC + ", ";
var outputStr = lineA + lineB + lineC;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're missing the `+` marks before `binA`, `binB`, and `binC` on lines 24, 25, and 26 :) You have some invalid javascript, and it's throwing an error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You are making syntax error in javascript. Replace your output string block with

```
//make output string
var lineA = "a = " + strA + " = "+ binA + ", ";
var lineB = "b = " + strB + " = "+ binB + ", ";
var lineC = "c = " + strC + " = "+ binC + ", ";
var outputStr = lineA + lineB + lineC;
```

It will work for you. Thanks